# C++/Linux: Using c++11 atomic to avoid partial read on dual-mapped mmap region

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, atomic, mmap

I have a program which has two threads. One thread (Writer Thread) writes to a file while the other consuming (Reader Thread) the data from the first. In the program, the same region of the file is mapped twice: one with read & write permission for Writer Thread, another just with read permission for Reader Thread. (The two mapped regions have different pointer/virtual address from mmap as expected). I attempt use a C++11 atomic to control the memory order.

Here is what I have in my mind:

Writer Thread:

1. Create the data content (fixed size) in the memory mapped region with write permission.
2. Update the atomic variable with release memory order.

Reader Thread:

1. Continuously poll on the atomic variable with acquire memory order till there is/are new messages.
2. If there is an outstanding message, read the data from the read only memory mapped region.

Questions

- Even though the read-only mmap region and writable mmap region are referring the same file region, they have different virtual memory addresses. Could the atomic variable protect partial read here? (i.e. if the reader thread saw the atomic variable is updated with acquire semantics, will the read only memory region just have partial message or the message is not yet visible at all?) (It seems to me that if the two virtual memory are mapped to the same physical memory page(s), it should work.)
- What if Reader Thread using read system call instead of read-only mmap region? Could the atomic memory variable avoid partial read?

I have written a test program that seems to work. However, I would like to be advised by a more experienced programmer/Linux expert whether it should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using different virtual memory ranges does not change things here. For proof note that atomic operations work just fine between two processes using the same shared memory. Each may have it mapped at a different virtual address.

What is important is that it references the same piece of physical memory.

The `read()` system call does not do anything to lock memory or access it atomically. It is simply a `memcpy()` done in the kernel from the file cache to user space. If another CPU is writing into that memory it can get a partial read.

Comment: Does it mean that for question 1, given the Reader Thread detected the updated count via the atomic variable (which is not on the mapped region but shared with the Writer Thread), the corresponding read memory access of the fixed size message should have complete message? (Since the atomic variable is write released after the memory write on the writable region.) For Question 2, by retaining the atomic variable mechanism, using read to access the region instead of memory mapped region should have the entire message as well. Am I right? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is perfectly valid and safe. The release in the writer thread and acquire on the reader thread guarantee a happens before relation. To quote the stadard :
29.3.2 2 An atomic operation A that performs a release operation on an atomic object M synchronizes with an atomic operation B that performs an acquire operation on M and takes its value from any side effect in the release sequence headed by A
 As a side note your bottleneck would most probably be the file operations so atomics instead of mutex wouldn't probably have an observable effect on performance.

Answer (score -4):

It does not seem like you need atomics here at all. What you need is a volatile variable. Atomicity would be ensured by OS itself, since the memory is backed by a file.

**EDIT.**

I see a bunch of people downvoted this answer, and in absence of meaningful comments I will assume people didn't understand it, and just reacted to suggested usage of volatile in context of multithreaded application. I will try to explain my position.

Reads and writes to memory backed files are atomic as long as corresponding `read()` and `write()` system calls are atomic, and those are atomic as long as memory buffer size does not exceed PIPE_BUF. (4K on Linux if memory serves). They also guarantee ordering. So, as long as you are `memcpy`ing chunks of less than 4K, you are good as long as the call has made it through compiler optimizations.

`Volatile` is needed exactly for this - to prevent compiler from optimizing reads and writes to this memory, and used exactly as prescribed.

On a side note, with exactly the same design on AIX, we've seen a huge performance degradation with compared to slighly modified design, when the writer uses `write()` to update the memory mapped file directly. Not sure if it is AIX quirk - but if performance is important, you might want to do some benchmarking.

Comment: Don't advise use of volatile, which is dangerous and useless on anything except Visual Studio.

Comment: @ZanLynx, seems like neither you, nor other downvoters understood what I was saying. I am not advising on volatile because it has anything to do with Visual Studio. I am advising on volatile because it is applicable in current scenario.

Comment: read() and write() are not atomic with respect to memory map accesses.

Comment: @ZanLynx, `read` and `write` know nothing about memory map access. They can not be atomic or non-atomic with regards to it.

Comment: presumably volatile would be potentially slower because of inhibiting optimizations and possibly less portable as it assumes certain cpu architectures. an atomic would probably be faster since it allows for optimizations, and it declares the intent (both to the reader of the code and to the compiler)

Comment: @Arvid, why would it be the case? In this scenarion, it doesn't assume anything about CPU (would work on non-coherent SPARC the same way) and doesn't prevent optimization any more than atomic. If anything, it is less pessimistic about optimization, as it allows code rearrangments to cross volatile variable access - this is not allowed for atomic.

Comment: this would be my guesses/fears why volatile would be less efficient: 1. The order of writes must maintain consistent 2. presumably the data must be flushed to RAM immediately (as opposed to being shared via L2 or L3). volatile has historically been used to communicate with other devices connected to the memory bus, the interface between the abstract machine and the real world is the memory bus. with atomics, all you ask for is other *cores* to see your memory.

Comment: @Arvid, volatile is completely unknown to CPU (and L caches are generally unknown to compiler), so any talks about volatile and caches are moot. Volatile is a pure compiler thing, which prevents compiler from ommitting reads from memory region (or writing). This is the only thing we need here. All memory ordering, caches and everything will be provided by mechanics of memory mapped files.

Comment: that might be the case with your compiler and arch. I am suggesting that an implementation (of the abstract machine) is free to have a different interpretation of what it means for a read and write to volatile memory to be "visible". My understanding is that historically it has meant it being visible to devices outside of the CPU, on the bus. But that's all implementation defined. It seems reasonable to assume that "visible" includes being visible to other threads, but as far as I understand, there's no language in the standard to support that.

Comment: @Arvid, no. You somehow completely missed my point. The only thing you need to do is to prevent compiler-related optimization of memory reads (without any regards to threading) - this is what volatile does. CPU visibility will be managed by OS/CPU in tandem by the nature of memory mapped file. This is guaranteed.

Comment: it is not guaranteed by the C or C++ standard. That makes it *not portable*. There are architectures where you need to issue specific instructions to the CPU to make your thread's memory writes visible to other threads.

Comment: @Arvid, you keep missing a point. memory mapped files ARE NOT part of C or C++ standard, and of course, standard does not guarantee anything about it. mmap call itself is not portable. it is OS which provides mmap call, and it is OS which provides guartantees I am talking about.

Comment: mmap is defined by opengroup. afaict the spec. does not mention synchronization. Which makes sense, how else could you implement mmap on PowerPC? have every page cause a fault in order to invoke a release fence? Anyway, I was just trying to explain why people (probably) voted down your answer.